# Tag chaining in Rails URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, tags, nested

I want to implement tags in my Rails application but I'm having trouble with one specific feature of that implementation. You see I want to make it possible for users to specify multiple tags in the url scheme, something like `http://domain/tags/:id1/:id2/...`. Has anyone implemented something like this in Rails or know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want something called "Route Globbing":

```
match 'tags/*tag_ids' => 'tags#lots_of_tags'
```

Then in `lots_of_tags` action you'd have `params[:tag_ids]` array of provided tag ids or a string in form of `id1/id2` (not sure which one, you should test it by yourself).

More info on this in [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing):